# Can't fix AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, file, exception

I wanted to export data as a chart/graph (whatever you say in English) and it worked beautifully in my IDE. But after building the program, I get greeted with this beautiful message:

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: .\charts
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:506)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:693)
        at de.yeet.handlers.ChartHandler.generateChart(ChartHandler.java:61)
        at de.yeet.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

I already tried fixing this problem by using the deprecated File API, which didn't work out either. Like I said, the code works fine in IntelliJ. Here's the code I used:

```js
try {
        Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("./charts"));
} catch (FileAlreadyExistsException ignored) {}
        
        String fileName = "./charts/chart-" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

        BitmapEncoder.saveBitmapWithDPI(chart, fileName, BitmapEncoder.BitmapFormat.PNG, 300);
```

The graph exporting is being handled by the XChart library. I'd be very grateful for any help. It was probably some small, stupid mistake on my part somewhere

Comment: `Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("./charts"))` is likely trying to create a directory relative to the working directory. What is your working directory? Does your application have sufficient privileges to create a directory there?

Comment: @Slaw I tried different directories, one on my data drive (H:\Programs\test.jar) and another one on my desktop (C:\Users\User\Desktop\test) with the same results

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the problem using Java 13.0.1 on Windows 10 Home. It may not help, but try to create a [mre] then add it to your question via an [edit].

Comment: @Slaw Not 'likely'. *Definitely'. `.` *is* the current working directory.

Comment: @OP If you ignore the exception on creating the directory you shouldn't be surprised that a subsequent access to it fails. Print the exception to see why.